# Картинки большие для экранов 1368x768

Tags: html, css

В макете есть две картинки, которые смотрятся на 1920 экранах отлично, а на экранах 1366 они сливаются в одну картинку(использую сетку bootstrap). Как тут быть? И как вообще верстать, если макет под 1920, а экран 1366.

Comment: Это дизайнер должен вам рассказать, как тут быть. // «как вообще верстать» — любой современный браузер имеет инструменты для проверки адаптивности, которые позволяют задать сколь угодно большие и сколь угодно малые размеры страницы, и неважно какой экран

Comment: css `@media screen` вам в помощь. А в бутстрап сетке есть свои классы для этого. col-(md, xs, ...), может еще что-то, давно в бутсрапе не был)

Comment: Т.е. любой размер изображения я могу адаптировать под 1366 не уменьшая само изображение?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WcxuiV9 
Вот пример того, что происходит)

Comment: в col у вас тип экрана не указан, вот тут пример как надо https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/, а вот размеры экранов https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте картинкам класс "img-fluid". Они начнут адаптироваться под размер контейнера, в котором находятся.